# Script to setup a validator using a .js and api

Tags: polkadot-js

I was wondering how to add a validator to a substrate chain using the API. I want to replicate the steps in the polkadot.js app:

1. Network -> Stash -> Account Actions
2. Click on validator (+)
3. Set the stash account, controller account, value bonded and
4. Set the keys from rotateKeys and the reward.

I can not find how the UI (what APIs) does it call to do steps 3 and 4.

Thanks very much
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI just calls the extrinsics as exposed by [the staking module](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#staking). Specifically -

- bonding via [api.tx.staking.bond(...)](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#bondcontroller-multiaddress-value-compactu128-payee-palletstakingrewarddestination) setting the controller, value bonded and payee from the stash account
- keys via [api.tx.session.setKeys(...)](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#bondcontroller-multiaddress-value-compactu128-payee-palletstakingrewarddestination) setting the keys from the controller account (proof is empty, not yet implemented on Substrate)
- validate via [api.tx.staking.validate(...)](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#bondcontroller-multiaddress-value-compactu128-payee-palletstakingrewarddestination) from the controller with the validator preferences (e.g. commission, blocking status)

Additional stuff of interest may be [setController](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#setcontrollercontroller-multiaddress) to change a controller, [setPayee](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#setpayeepayee-palletstakingrewarddestination) to adjust the reward destination and [bondExtra](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#bondextramax_additional-compactu128) should additional funds be bonded. These are all for management of the validator.